# How can I disable the autoparagraph feature of ckeditor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, ckeditor

JS code. It is not able to solve the problem.

```
   Template.addP.onRendered(function(){
        $('#basketSpace').ckeditor(function(){
          $('.cke').css({'border':'2px solid silver'});
          CKEDITOR.config.autoParagraph = false
        });
      });
```

I have a config.js file but the below code gives an error of "ckeditor is not defined"

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
 {
   config.autoParagraph = false
 };
```

Please help. If I have to do some tweaks to the code in config file, can you explain the reasons behind in doing so.
 
How do I pass the config information to the CKeditor?
What should its syntax be?

Comment: Are you using the `config.js` file located in `/public/ckeditor`?

Comment: Sorry for replying so late but i am not using the config.js file located in /public/ckeditor. I hope it is not embarrasing but I created a new config.js file.

Comment: I think you have two options: Either you move `ckeditor` to `/client/compatibility` and use your separate custom configuration or you keep `ckeditor` in your `/public` directory and add your custom configuration parameters to `/public/ckeditor/config.js`.

Comment: I have used the second option and tried to modify the /public/ckeditor/config.js but still it is wrapping the content in a p tag. Basically this is the code that I have used:-<br /> CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
 config.autoParagraph = false;
"default codes here"
};

Comment: Sorry but it did not work.

Comment: Could you please share a repository?

Comment: This is the repository for the config file https://bitbucket.org/realred4life/configforck/downloads